# What's an Elmer Cipher

Tags: cryptography, encryption

What's an Elmer Cipher? Where can I find a reference on this cipher algorithm?

Comment: Where did you hear of this Elmer Cipher?  It might help to know what you're looking for other than its apparently obscure name...

Comment: I was asked to use this Cipher to encrypt something. And was told that this is an Asymmetric Cipher. Couldn't find any results googling...could have been misspelt.

Comment: I am tempted to make a Looney Tunes-welated pun hewre, however I am not cwever enough to.

Comment: Is this for work or school?  Ask your instructor or client for clearer instructions, and unless this is actually a research project they should be willing to give a clearer idea of what they want.

Comment: It is very similar to a Henway.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that it was supposed to be [El Gamal](http://www.usna.edu/Users/math/wdj/book/node48.html). It fits the rest of your description (i.e., it's an asymmetric/public-key cipher).

Comment: I've heard of that but this is spelt as "Elmer"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a misheard [LM Hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LM_hash)?

Or maybe [this](http://www.rinkworks.com/dialect/dialectp.cgi?dialect=fudd&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630938/whats-an-elmer-cipher&inside=1) is what you're after ;)